# Groovy constructor problem

Tags: groovy

When the constructor of the class below is executed during my unit tests I get the error:

> No signature of method: static
>   grails.plugin.flashhelper.args.AnonymousArgumentsResolver.getDefaultMessages()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   ([Ljava.lang.Object;) values:
>   [[message number 1]]

```
class AnonymousArgumentsResolver extends AbstractArgumentsResolver {

    private final args

    AnonymousArgumentsResolver(methodArgs) {

        super(methodArgs[0], getDefaultMessages(methodArgs))

        this.args = methodArgs
    }

    private final getDefaultMessages(methodArgs) {

        if (methodArgs.size() > 1) {
            methodArgs[1..-1].find { it instanceof String || it instanceof List }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `getDefaultMessages` to be a `static` method everything works fine. I've no idea why Groovy requires this method to be static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't that also need to be static in java?

You are trying to call an instance method in a call to super(), where no instance yet exists...

Comment: So it's only a problem because the call is within `super()`, not because it's within a constructor? Does the restriction that `super()` has to be the first line in a constructor also apply in Groovy?

Comment: Yeah, after the call to super() you should be able to call it hassle free, and afaik, groovy still has the "first line" restriction for calls to super() from the constructor...